# Setting Sybase ASE 15.5 run on Windows Server 2003 machine that only use IPv6

Tags: sql, ipv6, sap-ase

I am going to install Sybase ASE 15.5 on a Windows Server 2003 machine. This W2K3 only use IPv6.

I successful installed Sybase on that machine.
I can also check it by command:

```
isql -U sa -P -S SYBSERVER
```

but I can not configure the IP in **DSEDIT** utilities (or the file %SYABSE%\ini\ **sql.ini**) to remote this Sybase server on another machine

The default content is:

```
[SYBSERVER_XP]
master=NLWNSCK,SYBSERVER,5001 
query=NLWNSCK,SYBSERVER,5001 


[SYBSERVER]
master=NLWNSCK,SYBSERVER,5000 
query=NLWNSCK,SYBSERVER,5000
```

The W2K3 IPv6 address is: **2001:dc9::94:60**. I try to change the sql.ini to:

```
[SYBSERVER_XP]
master=TCP,2001:dc9::94:60,5001 
query=TCP,2001:dc9::94:60,5001 


[SYBSERVER]
master=TCP,2001:dc9::94:60,5000 
query=TCP,2001:dc9::94:60,5000
```

but I cannot ping the Sybase server.

**How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

It seems too old and you may have already figured it out.

Try this

> [SYBSERVER]
>   master=tcp,ether,SYBSERVER.v6,5000 
>   query=tcp,ether,SYBSERVER.v6,5000

Also check the errorlog to see if sybase is listening now on IPV6